# WP Корректировка глубины комментариев для поста

Tags: wordpress, комментарии

На странице поста вывожу коментарии, через шаблон `comments.php` использую функцию [wp_list_comments()](https://misha.agency/wordpress/wp_list_comments.html)

```
<div id="comments" class="replacedText comments-area">
    <?php
    if (have_comments()) :
        ?>
        <p class="comments-title"><?php _e('Comments:', 'am') ?><?php echo get_comments_number() ?></p>
        <?php the_comments_navigation(); ?>
        <ol class="comment-list">
            <?php
            wp_list_comments(
                array(
                    'style' => 'ol',
                    'short_ping' => true,
                    'avatar_size' => 60,
                )
            );
            ?>
        </ol>
        <?php the_comments_navigation();
        if (!comments_open()): ?>
            <p class="replacedText no-comments textReplace"><?php esc_html_e('Comments are closed', 'am'); ?></p>
        <?php endif; endif;
    comment_form(); ?>
</div>
```

Вопрос - Почему в генерируемом `html` списке ответов первый коментарий имеет классы с глубиной `depth-1`. И все остальные, даже если пользователь жмет на кнопку Ответа конкретному пользователю, он тоже идет с классом `depth-1` Как это исправить ?
[image: Коментарий]